# MSEn of data error Mobj unable to be identified

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, entropy

'def MSEn(dataset_mus, Mobj, Scales=3, Methodx='coarse', RadNew=0, Plotx=False):
class MSobject:
x=(5,2,[3.2])
Mobj = MSobject(x)
dataset_mus=np.squeeze(dataset_mus)

```
Func2 = globals()[Methodx.lower()]
MSx = np.zeros(Scales)


for T in range(1,Scales+1):
    print(' .', end='')
    Temp = Func2(Sig,T)        

                
    MSx[T-1] = Temp2
CI = sum(MSx)
if np.any(np.isnan(MSx)):
    print('Some entropy values may be undefined.')

if Plotx:
   figure()
   ax1 = axes()   
   ax1.plot(np.arange(1,Scales+1), MSx, color=(8/255, 63/255, 77/255), linewidth=3)
   ax1.scatter(np.arange(1,Scales+1), MSx, 60, color=(1,0,1))
   ax1.set_xlabel('Scale Factor',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold',color=(7/255, 54/255, 66/255))
   ax1.set_ylabel('Entropy Value',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold',color=(7/255, 54/255, 66/255))
   ax1.set_title('Multiscale %s (%s-graining method)'%(Mobj.Func.__name__,Methodx), 
                 fontsize=16,fontweight='bold',color=(7/255, 54/255, 66/255))      
   show()
return MSx, CI
```

MSEn(dataset_mus,Mobj.x)'

error
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pm/zc3gg3ts2x17sm0r11qd66k00000gn/T/ipykernel_89686/2723706301.py in 
30        show()
31     return MSx, CI
---> 32 MSEn(dataset_mus,Mobj.x)

NameError: name 'Mobj' is not defined' '

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Mobj needs to be defined.
`Mobj= EH.MSobject('SampEn',m=2,r=0.15)`
this will create a sample entropy object with the given parameters and then you can call MSen function to calculate multiscale entropy.
I am working on the same problem right now. But my code works for a large data but throws error for smalller data.